# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Which are some of the properties of the metric $\rho(x_1,x_2)=\frac{d(x_1,x_2)}{1+d(x_1,x_2)}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Which are some of the propertis of the metric $$\rho(x_1,x_2)=\dfrac{d(x_1,x_2)}{1+d(x_1,x_2)}$$

I mean, if $(X,d)$ is complete or separable, then one can conclude that $(X,\rho)$ is so? and there is another properties?

Comment: $\rho$ has the same Cauchy sequences, the same convergent sequences, and the same limits as $d$. Except it's bounded, whereas $d$ might not be. Perhaps a bit more can be said?

Comment: That must means that if $(X,d)$ is complete, then $(X,\rho)$ does so, but if every  Cauchy sequence is bounded then $(X,\rho)$ would be always complete

Comment: Indeed: if $d$ is complete then so is $\rho$, and if $d$ is separable then so is $\rho$.

Comment: And what about the conversely?

Comment: Sure, the converse holds. It's not that hard to see: first, if $\delta>0$ then $d \leq \delta$ implies $\rho \leq \delta$. On the other hand, if $0<\delta<1$ then $\rho \leq \delta/2$ implies $d \leq \delta$. Thus at least for *small* distances, the two metrics are essentially the same. They only differ for *large* distances, which are not relevant to Cauchiness, convergence, separability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian said,

> for small distances, the two metrics are essentially the same. They only differ for large distances, which are not relevant to Cauchiness, convergence, separability, etc.

It may be instructive to compare $\rho$ to the metric $\tilde \rho(x_1,x_2)=\min(1,d(x_1,x_2))$. This definition makes it clear that $\tilde \rho$ is identical to $d$ at small scales. And the metrics $\rho$ and $\tilde \rho$ are comparable, since $ \frac12 \tilde\rho \le  \rho  \le  \tilde \rho $
(which is easy to check).